# SugarCRM SugarLogic Formulas

Tags: php, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM I'm trying to make a dependent field that will be visible if the Sales Stage is equal to "Closed Won" or "Closed Lost."

Using the Formula Builder I found that I can get it to recognize one this way:

```
equal($sales_stage,"Closed Won")
```

But I don't understand what formula(s) to use to get both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
or(equal($sales_stage,"Closed Won"),equal($sales_stage,"Closed Lost"))
```